# How to open a wikipathway (as a pathway) in cytoscape?

Tags: wiki, cytoscape

I am new to Cytoscape, my objective is to visualize gene expression data in a pathway. I have successfully uploaded Kegg pathways to Cytoscape, but missing nodes/edges are frequent compared to online Kegg pathways so I was hoping to turn to Wikipathways.

I am unable however to load Wikipathways pathways: I have tried using both Cytoscape 3.8.2 and 3.6 (version listed as "works with Wikipathways app Version 3.3.7"): I install Wikipathways app using the app manager, in the Network search tool I am able to choose WikiPathways in the drop-down menu and search for a pathway but no list of results opens. "Exception executing task: premature end of file" appears in the task history.

I am on MAC OS 10.13.6 (high sierra).

Any help would be appreciated,

Natalie

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pathViso? It allows wikipathways downloaded as a pathway and is also updated on a regular basis. In addition, one can also download Reactome pathways.

Comment: Hi A1aks, 
Thanks for your advice - I haven’t yet but was planning too.
I was hoping to be able to try both the wikipathways and kegg pathways on Cytoscape, and the wikipathways on pathvisio (reactome too then, thanks). 
I had a preference for cytoscape as I’ve started to get the hang of the styles and I know I will be able to visualise my differential expression data as I have planned. 
Thanks again for your help, 
N

Comment: Hi Natalie. One another advise. There are beautiful pathway enrichment apps called ClueGo and CluePedia that allows you multiple pathway databases to query and investigate the molecules within a specific pathway. Wiki pathways and reactome plus GO and KEGG can be combined. Hope it helps! Cheers.